# Rails - PQconsumeInput() SSL Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, controller

I am running a Rails application. For one particular controller, I get the following error about one in ten times that it is loaded.

```
[ApplicationController.render_error] PQconsumeInput() SSL error: internal error
["/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `async_exec'", "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:592:in `block in exec_no_cache'", "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `block in log'", "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'", "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:460:in `log'"
```

That's not the full stacktrace, because the full stacktrace is very long. I can post it upon request.

To the best of my knowledge, it only appears whenever the controller is under "heavy" load. I say "heavy" because it is only a few requests per second, but that is more traffic than my application usually gets.

I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of it. I'm almost at the point of putting a while loop and rescue block around the entire controller so that it can retry several times in the case of failure.

Please let me know if you have any insight.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `pool: 1` in your `config/database.yml`

Comment: I have already taken this step some time ago, and it did not fix the problem. Thanks for the help though.